# How to make the contents of .exe file unreadable in notepad

Tags: windows, security, exe, credentials

We had a problem at my office with people needing to use k-lite codec pack which is needed by our sound engineers (https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) on non admin accounts. Someone came up with the idea of making an .exe file in visual studio with the admin credentials to launch the k-lite as admin without having to give the admin privileges to the sound engineers.

Only trouble is by right clicking the .exe file and opening it in Notepad, you can get the credentials. Is there a way to hide the contents ? Compile them to machine code ? I'm not sure how to do this under windows 10.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

So I found how to do it, I used an obfuscator and I put the password in encrypted format and packaged a decoder with it. AES encryption.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend having a read over protecting .exe from reverse engineering, this may give you some insight into making the .exe unreadable. [Protecting executable from reverse engineering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481668/protecting-executable-from-reverse-engineering)

Comment: Thanks :) hopefully, my comment might have helped someone